# Problems with timestamp on mysql (php)

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, timestamp

I have made the following table on **mysql** to save the time that a client visit the page:

```
CREATE TABLE `visitas` ( 
 `**idv**` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `**fecha**` timestamp **DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**,
 `**ip**` varchar(15)  
 PRIMARY KEY (`**idv**`))
```

On **php** I run the next query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `visitas`(`ip`) VALUES ('$ip')");
```

The problem is that mysql save the time of the United States, and I want the time of Mexico.

I have tryed:

```
mysql_query("SET time_zone = '-06:00'");
```

but it doesnt take effect.

Please help me to make that mysql automatically save the time that i want.

Answer (score 0):

To set timezones with mysql, use `SET GLOBAL time_zone = '-06:00';`

or just set it with php

```
mysql_query("insert into visitas(ip, timestamp) values ('$ip', '". date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()) ."');
```

also, dont use `mysql`, look at [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: castis, Yes that is one solution. But I want to learn how to make it work with mysql :(